# Disable a form if the other is updatable

Tags: forms, fragment, jdeveloper

I'm using page fragments to create a view and in the same page I have two forms to view / update specific information.

What I want know if it's possible to disable one form (or button, since it's the way I use to change from readable to updatable) based on if the other is in updatable mode.

Simplifying I have form A and B, both in the same page as readable. When I select A to update I want B to disable the option to edit until A is back to read mode, and the same to B form.

Can anyone help me?

---Update

Flows

A
[image: Flow for simple customer data]

B
[image: Flow for detail customer data]

In each fragment (view) I have a button that as an action to the fragment (edit)

What I need is to disable the button from B.view when A button is pressed and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

If the forms are part of separate taskflows and these taskflows are used on the page as regions, then you will need to enable inter-region communication, so that an action in one region can affect the data and behavior  of other region:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/adfregioninteraction-155145.html

For your use case, contextual events can serve the purpose:

http://rohanwalia.blogspot.com/2013/07/contextual-events-basic-step-by-step.html
http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/05/using-contextual-event-in-oracle-adf.html
https://blogs.oracle.com/raghuyadav/entry/refresh_bounded_taskflows_acro

To implement your case, follow the tutorials provided above with following changes:

Pass a boolean value in the customPayLoad of event

```
<event name="DisableButtonEvent" customPayLoad="${'true'}"/>
```

In the event handler method assign the payLoad value to a scope variable:

```
  public void handleDisableButtonEvent(String payLoad) {
         AdfFacesContext adfFacesContext = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         Map pageFlowScope = adfFacesContext.getPageFlowScope();
         pageFlowScope.put("disableButton", payLoad);         
     }
```

Use the scope variable for disabled property of button on second region

```
  <af:commandButton text="EditButoonB" id="cb1"
                    disabled="#{pageFlowScope.disableButton ne null? pageFlowScope.disableButton : false}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @amishra. I have been reading the links you send me but none of them refrences pages with fragments.
In my case I have a form in each fragment. 
How can I reference a component from another fragment?
thk

Comment: I believe you have two task flows, each having fragments with form A and B respectively, on the page as regions?

Comment: Modified my answer to include the scenario of having form A and B in different regions

Comment: Thk for your reply @amishra, I have been reading the links you send me and I have a question, it looks to me that it is only possible to show the attributes from the same, or other VO with the 'fire Event', but what i need is to disable a component (button) in the other fragment, and its only function is to move between fragments

Comment: Modified the answer again to briefly describe how disabling of components across the regions will be achieved using Contextual events